# CPLEX OPL : Overflow occurred, please use oplrun -profile

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl

I am running a fairly large model in OPL, it has 576723 constraints, 1132515 variables, 3855 binary, 27150711 Non zero co-efficients.
At about 12 minutes the optimisation stops, it says 1 solution but displays no solution. In the profiler tab I get the Overflow occurred, please use oplrun -profile     message.

### The Engine log looks as below  ( Updated on 24th Sep):

```
Found incumbent of value 0.000000 after 0.02 sec. (30.57 ticks)
Presolve has eliminated 65039 rows and 117138 columns...
Presolve has improved bounds 1277962 times...
Aggregator has done 20701 substitutions...
Aggregator has done 42701 substitutions...
Aggregator has done 65901 substitutions...
Aggregator has done 89601 substitutions...
Aggregator has done 114601 substitutions...
Aggregator has done 141901 substitutions...
Aggregator has done 172001 substitutions...
Aggregator has done 205101 substitutions...
Aggregator has done 242201 substitutions...
Aggregator has done 285501 substitutions...
Aggregator has done 339801 substitutions...
Aggregator has done 425001 substitutions...
Tried aggregator 2 times.
MIP Presolve eliminated 65049 rows and 119516 columns.
MIP Presolve modified 3304560 coefficients.
Aggregator did 505533 substitutions.
Reduced MIP has 6138 rows, 507466 columns, and 15507869 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 2761 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time = 52.98 sec. (140577.29 ticks)
Tried aggregator 1 time.
Reduced MIP has 6138 rows, 507466 columns, and 15507869 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 2761 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time = 4.59 sec. (4115.32 ticks)
Probing time = 0.33 sec. (193.08 ticks)
Clique table members: 674.
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 16 threads.
Root relaxation solution time = 5983.52 sec. (4525135.08 ticks)

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                            0.0000     4585.0158              ---
      0     0     1414.4727   839        0.0000     1414.4727    74713     ---
      0     0        cutoff              0.0000                5409203     ---
Elapsed time = 19950.47 sec. (18809991.19 ticks, tree = 0.01 MB, solutions = 1)

Clique cuts applied:  2
Cover cuts applied:  57
Implied bound cuts applied:  91
Flow cuts applied:  121
Mixed integer rounding cuts applied:  236
Gomory fractional cuts applied:  4

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             = 19950.63 sec. (18810086.10 ticks)
Parallel b&c, 16 threads:
  Real time             =    0.00 sec. (0.00 ticks)
  Sync time (average)   =    0.00 sec.
  Wait time (average)   =    0.00 sec.
                          ------------
Total (root+branch&cut) = 19950.63 sec. (18810086.10 ticks)

<<< solve


OBJECTIVE: 0

<<< post process


<<< done

Profiler Report
     Time      PeakMemory      SelfTime        LocalMem       Count  Nodes Description
 20,190.282  100%   9.902 G  100%   0.753    0% 879.507 M    9%     1    126  TOTAL
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%     256 B    0%     1      1    READING MODEL DEFINITION Ashes200_data
   38.626    0% 840.113 M    8%   0.128    0% 721.418 M    7%     1     97    LOADING MODEL Ashes200_data-0000025C59804DD8
    7.277    0% 103.191 M    1%   2.750    0%  84.547 M    1%     1     52      LOADING DATA D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data 3yr.dat
    0.005    0%      28 K    0%   0.005    0%     400 B    0%     1      1        INIT TimePeriods at 13:1-24 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.003    0%       8 K    0%   0.003    0%  54.047 K    0%     1      1        INIT PitBlocks at 14:1-25 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%      16 K    0%   0.001    0%  35.641 K    0%     1      1        INIT DumpBlocks at 15:1-25 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%     576 B    0%     1      1        INIT Stockpiles at 17:1-25 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%     424 B    0%     1      1        INIT Plants at 19:1-21 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.329    0%  22.695 M    0%   0.329    0%  18.362 M    0%     1      1        INIT Pathid at 21:1-22 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.002    0%       0 B    0%   0.002    0%     904 B    0%     1      1        INIT AverageGrade at 48:1-37 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%     864 B    0%     1      1        INIT DensityGradeBins at 49:1-42 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.002    0%       8 K    0%   0.002    0%   5.531 K    0%     1      1        INIT grade at 26:1-30 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%   5.516 K    0%     1      1        INIT oreTons at 27:1-32 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.002    0%       0 B    0%   0.002    0%   5.562 K    0%     1      1        INIT density at 28:1-32 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%   5.523 K    0%     1      1        INIT wasteVolume at 29:1-36 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.068    0%       0 B    0%   0.068    0%   5.523 K    0%     1      1        INIT totalVolume at 30:1-36 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.002    0%       8 K    0%   0.002    0%   3.773 K    0%     1      1        INIT dumpVolume at 32:1-35 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%     872 B    0%     1      1        INIT resourceMaxCap at 35:1-40 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.002    0%       0 B    0%   0.002    0%     840 B    0%     1      1        INIT resourceMinCap at 36:1-40 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.013    0%       0 B    0%   0.013    0%   1.484 K    0%     1      1        INIT processMinCap at 37:1-46 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%   1.516 K    0%     1      1        INIT processMaxCap at 38:1-46 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%   1.477 K    0%     1      1        INIT GradeMin at 39:1-42 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.002    0%       0 B    0%   0.002    0%     936 B    0%     1      1        INIT SellPrice at 41:1-35 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%     840 B    0%     1      1        INIT wasteMiningCost at 42:1-41 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%     840 B    0%     1      1        INIT coalMiningCost at 43:1-40 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%     840 B    0%     1      1        INIT washCost at 44:1-34 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%     840 B    0%     1      1        INIT HaulageCost at 45:1-37 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%     848 B    0%     1      1        INIT StockPileRehandlingCost at 46:1-49 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%     128 B    0%     1      1        INIT SwellFactor at 52:1-24 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%      56 K    0%   0.001    0%   2.031 K    0%     1      1        INIT StockPileMaxCap at 56:1-52 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%   2.094 K    0%     1      1        INIT StockPileMinCap at 55:1-52 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%     128 B    0%     1      1        INIT DisountRate at 58:1-24 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.002    0%       0 B    0%   0.002    0%     128 B    0%     1      1        INIT DumpCapacity at 60:1-25 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.323    0%       0 B    0%   0.323    0% 130.461 K    0%     1      2        INIT PitBlocksType at 287:1-27 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%     976 B    0%     1      1          INIT ijk at 278:1-284:2 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.003    0%       0 B    0%   0.003    0%  57.203 K    0%     1      2        INIT DumpBlocksType at 273:1-34 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%     872 B    0%     1      1          INIT blockType at 263:1-268:3 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.273    0%      48 K    0%   0.273    0%  90.812 K    0%     1      2        INIT PitLagInfoXYB at 79:1-25 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%     872 B    0%     1      1          INIT xyz at 64:1-69:2 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.172    0%       0 B    0%   0.172    0%  55.266 K    0%     1      1        INIT DumpLagInfoXYB at 78:1-26 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.165    0%       0 B    0%   0.165    0%  20.453 K    0%     1      1        INIT DumpXYZ at 72:1-29 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0%   2.555 K    0%     1      1        INIT PlantXYZ at 73:1-26 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.002    0%       0 B    0%   0.002    0%   2.742 K    0%     1      1        INIT StockpilesXYZ at 74:1-35 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.003    0%      40 K    0%   0.003    0%  30.953 K    0%     1      1        INIT PitXYZ at 71:1-27 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    2.463    0%  56.422 M    1%   2.463    0%  45.421 M    0%     1      2        INIT rawPbd at 131:1-20 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   1.117 K    0%     1      1          INIT Raw at 121:1-130:2 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.011    0%     188 K    0%   0.011    0% 174.133 K    0%     1      1        INIT rawPbm at 132:1-20 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.024    0%     652 K    0%   0.024    0% 414.375 K    0%     1      1        INIT rawPbs at 133:1-20 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.625    0%  21.031 M    0%   0.625    0%  19.388 M    0%     1      2        INIT sourceDestD at 108:1-37 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%     744 B    0%     1      1          INIT sourceDestination at 103:1-106:2 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.005    0%     292 K    0%   0.005    0%  61.859 K    0%     1      1        INIT sourceDestM at 109:1-37 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.006    0%     240 K    0%   0.006    0% 177.469 K    0%     1      1        INIT sourceDestS at 110:1-37 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.002    0%       0 B    0%   0.002    0%  12.562 K    0%     1      2        INIT NullVariablesSet at 450:1-40 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%     744 B    0%     1      1          INIT nullVariables at 445:1-448:2 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
   28.810    0% 463.848 M    5%   0.000    0% 416.204 M    4%     1     29      PRE PROCESSING
    0.410    0%     640 K    0%   0.345    0% 649.023 K    0%     1      4        EXECUTE anonymous#1 at 90:1-8 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.065    0%     640 K    0%   0.065    0% 647.672 K    0%     1      3          INIT OntopDumpLag at 85:6-87:52 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       8 K    0%   0.000    0%     280 B    0%     1      1            INIT D at 81:11-14 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%     296 B    0%     1      1            INIT BottomPitBenNo at 82:24-25 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    5.935    0% 229.957 M    2%   5.935    0% 211.206 M    2%     1      8        EXECUTE anonymous#2 at 158:1-8 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%     624 B    0%     1      1          INIT emptysetd at 153:22-24 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   5.641 K    0%     1      2          INIT Pbd at 148:12-14 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   1.117 K    0%     1      1            INIT Path at 136:1-145:2 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%     840 B    0%     1      1          INIT emptysetm at 154:22-24 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   2.875 K    0%     1      1          INIT Pbm at 149:13-15 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%     792 B    0%     1      1          INIT emptysets at 155:22-24 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   2.875 K    0%     1      1          INIT Pbs at 150:12-14 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.902    0%  51.145 M    1%   0.788    0%  47.271 M    0%     1      2        EXECUTE anonymous#3 at 237:1-8 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.114    0%  51.145 M    1%   0.114    0%  47.271 M    0%     1      1          INIT hc at 233:1-31 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    1.678    0%   2.129 M    0%   1.029    0%   1.958 M    0%     1      2        EXECUTE anonymous#4 at 303:1-8 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.649    0%   2.129 M    0%   0.649    0%   1.957 M    0%     1      1          INIT OntopPit at 290:7-299:28 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    5.335    0% 117.746 M    1%   5.163    0% 106.703 M    1%     1      6        EXECUTE anonymous#5 at 367:1-8 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%     624 B    0%     1      1          INIT MaxS at 364:10-12 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.061    0%  42.777 M    0%   0.061    0%  39.647 M    0%     1      1          INIT splitPitBlocksPath at 353:1-34 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%       0 B    0%   0.001    0% 121.359 K    0%     1      1          INIT splitPitBlocksPathM at 354:1-35 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.001    0%     536 K    0%   0.001    0% 361.719 K    0%     1      1          INIT splitPitBlocksPathS at 355:1-35 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.109    0%   43.75 M    0%   0.109    0%  43.522 M    0%     1      1          INIT splitDumpBlocksPath at 356:1-35 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
   14.550    0%  62.246 M    1%  14.436    0%  48.431 M    0%     1      6        EXECUTE anonymous#6 at 470:1-8 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%     268 K    0%   0.000    0% 263.789 K    0%     1      1          INIT capBMT at 453:1-46 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.112    0%   50.91 M    1%   0.112    0%  47.161 M    0%     1      1          INIT capBDT at 455:1-50 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.002    0%     536 K    0%   0.002    0% 555.375 K    0%     1      1          INIT capBST at 457:1-50 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%     268 K    0%   0.000    0% 143.125 K    0%     1      1          INIT capBT at 459:1-35 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   147.5 K    0%     1      1          INIT capschedulePit at 461:1-44 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    2.101    0% 256.062 M    3%   0.009    0% 218.874 M    2%     1     10      INIT npv at 699:19-703:108 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   5.156 K    0%     1      1        INIT Dfbmt at 684:1-103 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.006    0%       0 B    0%   0.006    0%  419.82 K    0%     1      1        INIT Xbmt at 672:1-89 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   3.914 K    0%     1      1        INIT Dfbdt at 687:1-59 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    1.350    0% 108.723 M    1%   1.350    0% 106.255 M    1%     1      1        INIT Xbdt at 673:1-91 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   3.914 K    0%     1      1        INIT Dfbst at 690:1-58 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.012    0%   1.051 M    0%   0.012    0%1,020.648 K    0%     1      1        INIT Xbst at 674:1-91 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   4.805 K    0%     1      1        INIT Dfsmt at 694:1-87 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   3.758 K    0%     1      1        INIT Xsmt at 663:1-51 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.724    0% 109.227 M    1%   0.724    0% 106.847 M    1%     1      1        INIT ypt at 677:1-47 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.018    0%  16.035 M    0%   0.018    0% 315.047 K    0%     1      1      INIT schedulePit at 676:1-87 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.287    0%       0 B    0%   0.287    0% 875.367 K    0%     1      1      INIT OnBelowDump at 313:6-323:47 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.002    0%       0 B    0%   0.002    0% 202.047 K    0%     1      1      INIT scheduleDump at 668:1-52 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   2.156 K    0%     1      1      INIT StockPileVol at 54:1-45 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.003    0%     272 K    0%   0.003    0%  280.82 K    0%     1      1      INIT zbt at 675:1-70 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
  177.026    1%   9.063 G   92%  10.546    0% 158.001 M    2%     1      2    EXTRACTING Ashes200_data-0000025C59804DD8
  166.480    1%   8.179 G   83% 166.480    1%  17.213 M    0%     1      1      OBJECTIVE  at 714:1-716:4 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
 19,951.910   99%   4.281 G   43%5,989.816   30% 319.668 M    3%     1     13    CPLEX MIP Optimization
   52.990    0% 389.746 M    4%  52.990    0% 389.746 M    4%     1      1      CPLEX Pre Solve
    4.589    0% 256.008 M    3%   4.589    0% 256.008 M    3%     1      1      CPLEX Pre Solve
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%       0 B    0%     1      1      CPLEX Solve LP Relaxation
 13,904.515   69%    1.05 G   11%  23.882    0% 467.602 M    5%     1      9      CPLEX Generating Cuts for Root Node
 13,714.446   68%      52 K    0%   2.292    0%  78.424 M    1%     7      3        CPLEX Solve LP Relaxation
 13,711.520   68%       0 B    0%13,711.520   68% 110.169 M    1%     4      1          CPLEX Solve LP Relaxation
    0.634    0%      52 K    0%   0.634    0% 225.727 M    2%     1      1          CPLEX Pre Solve
  165.425    1% 604.797 M    6%   0.170    0% 604.797 M    6%     1      3        CPLEX Heuristics
  165.255    1% 324.707 M    3%   0.289    0%  81.177 M    1%     4      2          CPLEX Solve LP Relaxation
  164.966    1% 309.051 M    3% 164.966    1% 152.584 M    2%     2      1            CPLEX Solve LP Relaxation
    0.130    0%       0 B    0%   0.130    0%       0 B    0%     1      1        CPLEX Probing
    0.632    0% 225.676 M    2%   0.632    0% 225.676 M    2%     1      1        CPLEX Pre Solve
   21.967    0%   8.656 M    0%   0.009    0%   35.43 K    0%     1     12    POST PROCESSING
   21.958    0%   8.656 M    0%  17.082    0%  39.516 K    0%     1     11      EXECUTE anonymous#7 at 1300:1-1301:0 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.011    0%   8.656 M    0%   0.011    0%   9.328 K    0%     1      2        INIT solXbmt at 1252:21-112 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   1,000 B    0%     1      1          INIT SolXbmt at 1245:1-1250:2 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    2.327    0%       0 B    0%   2.327    0%   7.258 K    0%     1      2        INIT solXbdt at 1263:24-118 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   1,000 B    0%     1      1          INIT SolXbdt at 1255:1-1260:2 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.036    0%       0 B    0%   0.036    0%   7.352 K    0%     1      2        INIT solXbst at 1275:22-117 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   1,000 B    0%     1      1          INIT SolXbst at 1267:1-1272:2 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   7.258 K    0%     1      2        INIT solXsmt at 1284:21-111 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%   1,000 B    0%     1      1          INIT SolXsmt at 1277:1-1282:2 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    2.502    0%       0 B    0%   2.502    0%    6.18 K    0%     1      2        INIT solPath at 1297:21-84 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod
    0.000    0%       0 B    0%   0.000    0%     944 B    0%     1      1          INIT SolPath at 1291:1-1295:2 D:\PhD\Minex_Data\FINAL_PAPER2022\AshesPit200\Ashes_Pit200\Ashes200_data.mod

<<< profile
```

---

Kindly suggest how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use better units. An objective value of 8.95478e+11 indicates you are using cents instead of billions of dollars. Also, make sure any big-M constants are not larger than needed.

Comment: What happens if you use oplrun instead of the studio ?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for the suggestion. It was not very different with oplrun. I have also tried with oplrun -profile. I have updated the log above. Also based on the above suggestion I changed the units to millions and have relatively smaller numbers now, but that did not help either. Not sure where is the problem as I know practically solution to the problem exists.